# Trying to push log files to an array with perl and process the files

Tags: perl

The sample log files are as below,

```
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1013/harvester.log.20170410   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1013/harvester.log.20170303   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1013/harvester.log.20170406   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1011/harvester.log.20170307   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1011/harvester.log.20170306   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1012/harvester.log.20170405   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1011/harvester.log.20170304   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1014/harvester.log.20170305   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1011/harvester.log.20170410   
/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1011/harvester.log.20170303
```

Trying to to push today's log files to an array. But it doesn't produce any output or any errors.

The idea is to load today's log to array and process each file to search for "Error" and if it has an error then provide the output file name, file path and error (a sample one below),

```
HostName  |    Log Location  |      File Name   |    Error
host1011  |    /home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs/host1011/  | harvester.log.20170410    |    error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @files;
my $logDir = "/home/ajoy/alert-dc/testlogs";
my $Date = `date +%Y%m%d`;
my $pattern = "harvester.log.$Date";
chomp($Date);
find( 
    sub { push @files, $File::Find::name unless -d; }, 
    $logDir
);
foreach my $file (@files) {
     if ($file =~ $pattern) { print "$file"; }
}
```

Comment: What's inside `@files`? Use Data::Dumper to check. Also note that the `.` is a meta character in regex. It means _any character_. So you might want to escape that in your pattern. On top of that, I wouldn't shell out for `date`, but use Time::Piece instead, which is included in the Perl core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one small mistake in your code please chomp the `$date` before making the `$pattern`

```
chomp($Date);
my $pattern = qr/harvester\.log\.$Date/;
```

Or else chomp the `$pattern`

```
my $pattern = qr/harvester\.log\.$Date/;
chomp $pattern;
```

---

As per simbabque comment better use [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module so your code should be

```
my $Date = localtime->ymd("") ;
```

And the final code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Time::Piece;

my @files;
my $logDir = "yourdir";

my $Date = localtime->ymd("") ;

my $pattern = qr/harvester\.log\.$Date/; #dot will match the any character except new line so we should escape it. 

find( 
    sub { push @files, $File::Find::name unless -d; }, 
    $logDir
);
foreach my $file (@files) {
     if ($file =~ $pattern) { print "$file\n"; }
}
```

combining push and date check

```
find( 
    sub { push @files, $File::Find::name if($File::Find::name =~m/$pattern/ and -f) }, 
    $logDir
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, chomp $pattern and  Time::Piece module both worked fine.

can we combine pushing and pattern search to a single process so that  the array will have logs generated today

`find( 
    sub { push @files, $File::Find::name unless -d; }, 
    $logDir
);
foreach my $file (@files) {
     if ($file =~ $pattern) { print "$file\n"; }
}`

Comment: `my $pattern = "harvester\.log\.$Date"` doesn't escape the dots. In fact the backslashes don't make any difference to the resultant string at all. Since you're using the string as a regex pattern, it's best to compile it as such first. `my $pattern = qr/harvester\.log\.$Date/` is correct